# Creating an undirected graph given a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a List:

```
entry=['A','B','C','null','B','A','D','null','E','F']
```

Letters (vertexes) adjacent to each other form an edge. 'null' is a separator.

Each edge has weight 1. Edge (A,B) has weight two, since it occurs twice.

To visualize, above list will be this graph:
[image]

I want to create a dictionary, similar to adjacency list.

```
dict= {
'A':{'B':2,'D',1},
'B':{'A':2,'C':1},
'C':{'B':1},
'D':{'A':1},
'E':{'F':1},
'F':{'E':1}
}
```

Where first key is a vertex, second keys are neighboring vertexes with its weight values.

How to come up with above graph. If there are any other better way of representation of above graph, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: How about you show what code you tried first. Seems quite trivial to simply iterate the groups and add a number to each counter on a dictionary.

Comment: @JBernardo , I just want to come up with adjacency list as above, and I'll be using that for further calculations. Code is complicated, I simplified it to above problem so that is it simple to understand. It might be trivial, but I can't get that somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) your `entry` list to the graph dictionary as reduce (without an accumulator) looks at 2 adjacent elements at a time:

```
from functools import reduce

graph = {}

def add_edge(u, v):
    if u != 'null' and v != 'null':
        if u in graph:
            graph[u][v] = graph[u].get(v, 0) + 1
        else:
            graph[u] = {v: 1}
        if v in graph:
            graph[v][u] = graph[v].get(u, 0) + 1
        else:
            graph[v] = {u: 1}
    return v

entry = ['A','B','C','null','B','A','D','null','E','F']
reduce(add_edge, entry)

print(graph)
# {'B': {'A': 2, 'C': 1}, 'E': {'F': 1}, 'F': {'E': 1}, 'C': {'B': 1}, 'A': {'B': 2, 'D': 1}, 'D': {'A': 1}}
```

**Edit**:

A "purer" way to reduce would be to zip adjacent elements together and then reduce with an initializer:

```
def add_edge(graph, edges):
    u, v = edges
    if u != 'null' and v != 'null':
        # ... same thing as before
    return graph

entry = ['A','B','C','null','B','A','D','null','E','F']
graph = reduce(add_edge, zip(entry[:-1], entry[1:]), {})
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know anything about reduce. Lemme research that. But that solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: could you please just update script to deal with words, instead of letters?

Comment: @EricKlaus I don't see how this would be any different for words (since they're strings too).

Answer (score 1):

Piggy backing on @slider answer, you can also use `map` (which is builtin, no imports needed) for this:

```
graph = {}
def add_edge(l):
    u, v = l[0], l[1]
    if u != 'null' and v != 'null':
        if u in graph:
            graph[u][v] = graph[u].get(v, 0) + 1
        else:
            graph[u] = {v: 1}
        if v in graph:
            graph[v][u] = graph[v].get(u, 0) + 1
        else:
            graph[v] = {u: 1}
    return v

list(map(add_edge, [entry[i:i+2] for i in range(len(entry) - 1)]))

>>> graph
{'A': {'B': 2, 'D': 1},
 'B': {'A': 2, 'C': 1},
 'C': {'B': 1},
 'D': {'A': 1},
 'E': {'F': 1},
 'F': {'E': 1}}
```

The reason for using `list(map(func..))` is because for python 3, `map` returns a generator instead of executing, hence have to use list to force it to execute. The output of that line is not of interest to us. If you're using python 2, then you can just use `map(func..)`